# Given that f(x) is an even function. Indicate what can be said about the symmetry of the following function.

Tags: functions

The function is y=-3f(x)

I answered that it's odd by doing the odd/even tests. But I am not sure if I am doing this right, any help?

Comment: Explain why you think that this is odd?

Comment: I figured that it's odd by substituting f(-x) and -f(x) into the equation. But again I'm sure that this is wrong and that I'm missing a step, I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Well, you are given $f(-x)=f(x)$, yes?  And then we define $y(x)=-3f(x)$.  So, what is $y(-x)$?

Comment: so y(-x) = -3f(-x) wich will be 3fx(?) I just dont understand the correlation of f(x) being even and this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = \color{green}-3f(x)$.

$$g(\color{red}-x)=\color{green}-3f(\color{red}-x)=\color{green}-3f(x)=g(x)$$

Hence $g$ is an even function.

Remark:

If $f$ is even, we have $f(\color{red}-x)=f(x)$, that is we can get rid of the negative sign inside $f$. The negative in front of $3$ is not influenced at all.

Comment: But doesn't -3f(-x) become 3fx? so how can it be equal to −3f(x)? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: We know that $f(-x)=f(x)$, multiply both sides by $-3$, we have $-3f(-x)=-3f(x)$.

Comment: $f(-x) = f(x)$. Ergo $-3f(-x) = -3f(x)$

Comment: okay so say instead of -3f(x) it's f(x)-4, would you subtract both f(-x) & f(x) by 4?

Comment: Sure, if $f(x)=f(-x)$, we do have $f(x)-4 = f(-x)-4$.

Comment: So would something like 2f(x)+1 be even? I'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Let $g(x)=2f(x)+1$, verify if $g(x)=g(-x)$.